# How to inject a directive or component within an attribute directive?

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

Angular 2 rc 1, written in TypeScript.

I have an attribute directive with selector `myDirective`.  Its purpose is to build out a piece of html that I reuse often. To do its work, the matching class needs access to a custom component as well as another attribute directive. I'm having trouble figuring out how to inject an attribute directive or a component within `myDirective`'s class.

```
@Directive({selector: '[myDirective]'})
export class MyDirective{
    constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private elementRef:ElementRef) {
        let el = elementRef.nativeElement; //capture the HTML element host
        let innerElement = renderer.createElement(el,'my-component',null);
        renderer.setElementAttribute(innerElement,'myOtherDirective','');
    }
}
```

Usage: `<div myDirective></div>`

The generated HTML: `<div><my-component myOtherDirective=''></my-component></div>`

Problem is that `my-component` and `myOtherDirective` are not processed by the Angular template parser, and of course the browser does not recognize them.  I have two questions:

1. How can I inject another directive or component within my attribute directive?
2. Am I misusing the attribute directive here? Is a component better suited?

Answer (score 3):

This is a misuse of `Directive`
Create a `Component` instead, so you can use it like

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

Basic example: http://learnangular2.com/components/

**Update:** Here is the example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <div> I'm a parent component!!!
      <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
  `,
  directive: [ChildComponent]
})

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <div> I'm a child component!!!
    </div>
  `
})
```

- The member `directive` of the annotation `Component` references `ChildComponent`, i.e. tells the `ParentComponent` to use *things* from `ChildComponent`.
- Angular sees `selector: 'child-component'` in ChildComponent and injects it's template where it sees `child-component` tags in `ParentComponent` template.

The member `directive` of annotation `Component` is a bit misleading. You may think that only `Directive` can be references here, but it's also a place for referencing `Components`

For the attribute `Directive`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div my-directive> I'm a component with directive!!!
    </div>
  `,
  directive: [MyDirective]
})

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]'
})
```

You can pass a value using attribute directive

```
<div [my-directive]="I'm a value!"> I'm a component with directive!!!</div>
```

Check the official docs for details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

I'd recommend you to watch this video lesson https://youtu.be/_-CD_5YhJTA. It was extremely helpful for me.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion while awaiting a response and built a component. Guess I'm having a bit of trouble finding a clear demarcation between when a component is appropriate and when an attribute directive is. I think the best I can come up with is that if I need a view template, I should use a component.  Thumbs up for the suggestion; I still wonder how to inject an attribute directive in another.

Comment: That's exactly the difference. A component has a view, a directive doesn't.